# Flutter : Facebook audience network Banner error_message: No Fill, error_code: 1001 When back to previous route

Tags: flutter

I got this Error with Fb banner ad when I back to a previous route :

```
{error_message: No Fill, error_code: 1001, invalidated: false, placement_id: **************}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message is very obvious, this error means you implemented ad but ad is not filling. You have to upload your app to playstore and then your add will automatically fill.

Note: you have to download your app from playstore then it will show real ad.

I personally face this error and found this solution only.

You can test in test device:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/test/

Following reasons are mention by facebook:

```
Error 1001 - No Fill. May be due to one or more of the following:
User not logged into Native Facebook App on Mobile Device
Limit Ad Tracking turned on (iOS)
Opt out of interest-based ads turned on (Android)
No Ad Inventory for current user
Your testing device must have the native Facebook application installed.
Your application should attempt to make another request after 30 seconds.
```